# How generate *Compile log* buffer?

Tags: compilation

I switched to `Emacs 29.1` from `Emacs 26`.

The first time I opened `Emacs` I got:

```
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:81:2: Warning: defvar `jsons-parsed-regions' docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:208:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:228:6: Warning: value returned from (match-end 0) is unused
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:232:14: Warning: value returned from (match-end 0) is unused
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:232:14: Warning: value returned from (match-end 0) is unused
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:253:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): json-snatcher.el:311:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): request.el:394:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): request.el:880:25: Warning: ‘point’ is an obsolete generalized variable; use ‘goto-char’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): request.el:885:25: Warning: ‘point’ is an obsolete generalized variable; use ‘goto-char’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): request.el:1184:18: Warning: reference to free variable ‘auto-revert-notify-watch-descriptor-hash-list’
⛔ Warning (comp): json-mode.el:189:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters
```

I solved by upgrading these packages.

My question is: How can I generate this `*Compile Log*` for my tools (functions, scripts etc.)?

I accidentally used a key combination in a buffer and got this:

```
Compiling file /home/gabriele/SissaMedialab/elisp/production_macros.el at Fri Feb  2 12:36:51 2024
production_macros.el:72:9: Warning: global/dynamic var ‘MedialabElispPath’
    lacks a prefix
production_macros.el:75:9: Warning: global/dynamic var ‘TexFileSyncString’
    lacks a prefix
production_macros.el:75:2: Warning: defvar `TexFileSyncString' docstring wider
    than 100 characters
production_macros.el:89:9: Warning: global/dynamic var ‘TexFileLaTeXEngine’
    lacks a prefix
production_macros.el:163:2: Warning: defvar `TrimmedMargins-p' docstring wider
    than 100 characters
production_macros.el:235:2: Warning: defvar `TfracHighlight-p' docstring wider
    than 100 characters
production_macros.el:316:2: Warning: defvar `LessGrtrTextModeHighlight-p'
    docstring wider than 100 characters
```

I used `C-h l` but I wasn't able to find the function that generated this `*Compile log*` buffer. I also tried `eval-buffer` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*Compile-Log*` usually gets displayed after byte/native compiling some file/buffer. Two shortcuts for byte compilation are `C-c C-f` (`elisp-byte-compile-file`) and `C-c C-b` (`elisp-byte-compile-buffer`).